# How to handle .gitignore files in subfolders in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I've the following situation: I have a project checked out from Git. The project consists of several packages/folders. And then I have a .gitignore file on the root project directory and (in some cases) .gitignores on subfolders.
If I now commit some changes, eclipse also wants to commit all files and directories which are ignored in the subfolders. It seems that only the .gitignore from the root is used.

The project tree looks like this:

```
MyProject/src/.gitignore
MyProject/src/File1.java
MyProject/src/File2.java
MyProject/src/folder1/.gitignore
MyProject/src/folder1/ShouldAlsoBeIgnored.java
MyProject/src/folder2/File3.java
```

Comment: Please provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  example

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/1700321?

Comment: "git status" says "no changes to commit" what is correct. But eclipse wants to commit 100 files. So I guess it's a problem of eclipse.